# How to find a linear system of equation and how many equation will it be composed of?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^4$ as :

$u= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 1 \\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$
$v= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3 \\1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$
$u= \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 0 \\1\\2 \end{pmatrix}$

I have to find a system of equation of $Vect(u,v,w)$ but I always fail to find it...

How many equation must it have?

How to find it the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the third vector you denoted is actually $w$, we find that $x \in \text{vect}(u,v,w)$ if and only if $x = \lambda_1u + \lambda_2v + \lambda_3w$ where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$. This gives you your system of equations.

To find the number of equations, you can define a matrix and look at its rank: the matrix is the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
This matrix follows from $x = \lambda_1u + \lambda_2v + \lambda_3w$. If you use Gaussian Elimination, you should find that this matrix is equivalent to 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1.5\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3.5
\end{pmatrix}$$
so it has rank 3.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to find the number of equation then?

Comment: well suppose the rank is 2 (instead of 3), then it is possible to describe the space by 2 instead of 3 equations. Use Gaussian elimination to find out if there is a zero row in this matrix.

Comment: I never used matrix so it's a bit hard for me... How can I do it without that?

Comment: You have no idea what matrices are? Or you never tried to solve this using matrices? Note that matrices are just a way to denote systems of linear equations, so you could repeat the whole in equation-notation, try to eliminate variables and in this way find out wheather or not there are redundant equations...

Comment: I learn what is a matrix, but I don't know how to solve a system with a matrix.

Comment: You have not learned yet about rank of a matrix and Gaussian elimination? (Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations using matrices?)